# Size of class with static member and accessor

Tags: class, windows-phone-7, size

I have a question regarding efficiency. I am writing an app for windows phone 7 and care a lot about memory, as I am using extremely long lists.

My question is, what is the size of a class that apart from using normal properties like int, string etc, has also a static int property and an accessor property for the forementioned static field? I need to use a static field, but cannot  access it using databinding, thus my question.

An example:

```
private static int _property1;

public int Property1
{
    get { return _property1; }
}

public int property2;

public int property3;
```

I would be really grateful for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have static field _property1, which will be shared between all the instances of class, means it will create only one copy of _property1, if someone changes the value of static field it will reflect to every place. So it will increase the efficiency regardless you need to restrict the other users to set/reset static variables..

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I am aware of the static field size, but I have doubts about accessor property... What is it's size? If it is treated like a normal int, then there would be no point in creating the static property... I suppose it is not so obvious now, but suppose this static property is a list, then it makes a huge difference.

Comment: Yeah, Size of Object is only of size of datamembers(i.e. intance variables), As per your question what is size of accessor property? The answer is the Object does not have any constraints like size of accessor property, means it is like negligible in all the cases. So that ultimate answer is the accessor does not contribute to the size of Object regardless it is static or non-static.